# Timestamp field value is not fetching in cloudant query or HTTP API(Get with _find)

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

The timestamp field value is not fetching in Cloudant query or HTTP API (Get with _find).

```
https://<bluemix_url>/_find (with POST METHOD)
{"selector": {"activity": "walk"}}
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
{"activity": "","name":"iphone","timestamp": "2016-07-22T14:22Z"}
{"activity": "walk","name": "sony","timestamp": "2016-07-22T14:30Z"}
```

I have created index for both timestamp, name and activity field. I am not getting documents if I am trying to get the data based on "timestamp", "activity". I am getting value if I select based on "name" field. I don't know what is the reason. Help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post the query syntax for the actual query you're having trouble with? I took your example data and tested the query you described, and it works for me:  ```{
  "selector": {
    "timestamp": "2016-07-22T14:30Z",
    "activity": "walk"
  },
  "fields": [
    "_id",
    "_rev",
    "timestamp",
    "activity"
  ]
}```  I also have json-type indexes on "name", "timestamp", and "activity".

Comment: @Pari Margu - Are you still having an issue? If so, please see the previous comment.

Comment: I have some documents with timestamp field having null values. Is that reason I am getting null values? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I took your example data and tested the query you described, and it works
for me:

```
{"selector":{ "activity": "walk" }}
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
{"activity": "","timestamp": "2016-07-22T14:22Z"}
{"activity": "walk","timestamp": ""}
```

I also have json-type indexes on "timestamp" and "activity".
Can you please post the query syntax for the actual query you're having
trouble with?